# MPI_Send arguments

Tags: c, mpi

```
        #define SPEEDS 5
typedef struct
    {
      float directions[SPEEDS];
    } input;
    
    input data[1000];
    int start=10;
    int xx=10;
    
    MPI_Send(data + start * xx, yy, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

How can I understand the first argument of MPI_Send? data is just an array but we're adding and multiplying numbers to it?

Comment: This is equivalent to &data[start*xx]

Comment: That's more like skipping first 100 elements in the `data[]`, what's the value of `yy`?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `data + start * xx` is "address arithmetic": it means "the address of `data` plus `start*xx` times the size of whatever type is in `data`.

In other words, it's equivalent to

```
MPI_Send( &( data[start*xx] ), ....
```